# Select first appearance of item in last grouping

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, pdo, sequence

Confusing, but, here's the situation:

We've got sequence numbers which correspond to where a program sits at 1 minute intervals.

```
Sequence#  |  Timestamp
   1       |   2012-04-11 12:00:00
   2       |   2012-04-11 12:01:00
   2       |   2012-04-11 12:02:00
   2       |   2012-04-11 12:03:00
   3       |   2012-04-11 12:04:00
   5       |   2012-04-11 12:05:00
   5       |   2012-04-11 12:06:00
   6       |   2012-04-11 12:07:00
   1       |   2012-04-11 12:08:00
   2       |   2012-04-11 12:09:00
   2       |   2012-04-11 12:10:00
   2       |   2012-04-11 12:11:00
   3       |   2012-04-11 12:12:00
```

The duration of the sequences may change, but the interval is always the same (every 1 minute precisely).

As you can see, the sequences repeat. **How can I find the latest, starting occurance** of Seqence `n`?

So, if I wanted to search for sequence 2, I would want to return `2 | 2012-04-11 12:09:00` because it is the latest, starting occurance of sequence 2.

Comment: Where is the data?  In a database?  Or is it being read from a stream?

Comment: @PhilipKearns: Given that the question is tagged with [mysql]...

Comment: Yeah, context is kind of important here. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Those rows obviously have more information in them in my real database table. I need to return the row indicated in my question via an SQL query, but I'm unsure how to get the **start** of the most recent **group** (when grouping by sequence number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM `table_name` t1
LEFT JOIN `table_name` t2 
on t1.`Sequence` = t2.`Sequence` and 
   t1.`Timestamp` = t2.`Timestamp` + interval 1 minute
WHERE t1.`Sequence`=2 and t2.`Sequence` is null
ORDER BY t1.`Timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a294/4).

Comment: I don't think I follow how this works. Wouldn't this return the very first occurance of Sequence 2, in order of time? Your second `ON` requirement would never be true, so the left join would always have t2.Sequence as null, so every occurance of Sequence 2 satisfies this query and it would return the latest. My query is more complicated than this, so it's not easy to try this method, hence me needing to know what method is really going on here..

Comment: +1, it works. But if you could please explain how it's working..? My actual database is (stupidly) storing the timestamp as `year`, `month`, `day`... fields, not by choice, so I need to know what logic is going on here in order to replicate it with those fields.

Comment: @StuckAtWork: The second `on` condition will always be true, except for the very first record ever - it links the current timestamp to the previous one, one minute ago. Combining this with the first `on` condition links the current record to the last record, **if** they are the same sequence - making this a left join with an `is null` condition on the outer joined table is effectively the same as doing a `not exists` (the outer join / null where combination should perform better in MySQL).

Comment: @StuckAtWork: So, you've got the set of records (on t1) where there is no immediately previous record of the same sequence - or to put it another way, each starting occurence of a series of records with the same sequence. The `WHERE t1.\`Sequence\`=2` condition restricts this to sequence 2; ordering by t1.`Timestamp` DESCENDING returns them in reverse chronological order (latest first), while LIMIT 1 ensures only the first record (ie. the latest) is returned.

Comment: Oh I see now. That's.. well that's really clever, actually. It basically tells SQL to look until it finds a sequence 2 that isn't preceeded by another 2. Definitely the answer, though I'll have to figure out how to convert those silly individual fields to work with it. Thank you!

Comment: Since my IDs are sequential, I just used the ID number as a "previous timestamp". `ON t1.sequence = t2.sequence AND t1.id = t2.id + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want...

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `Sequence`=2 ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This query would output `2 | 2012-04-11 12:11:00` and not `2 | 2012-04-11 12:09:00` as you stated but I think `2 | 2012-04-11 12:11:00` is actually what you were looking for

Comment: I don't think it is - "the latest, **starting** occurance" (my emphasis).

Comment: Nope; looking for `12:09:00`. We're given two parameters, `startSeq` and `endSeq`. I need information form those rows from the beginning of `startSeq` to the end of `endSeq`, so I'd need the earlier (but still most recent grouping) of sequence 2 if `startSeq` is `2`.

Comment: I took the liberty of assuming it was in a mysql database since this question is tagged as mysql

Comment: Ok... I now understand what you are trying to do but you have me stumped there. I think you'll have to go through each record and compare the sequence number to the previous record and see if it is the same or not. Gimme a sec to throw some code together.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$desired_sequence=2;

$query="SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_errno()) { die( "ERROR ".mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) ); }

$found_desired=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['Sequence']==$desired_sequence)
    {
        $found_desired=1;
        $timestamp=$row['Timestamp'];
    }

    if( ($found_desired==1) && ($row['Sequence']!=$desired_sequence) )
    {
        return; // End the while loop because $timestamp will have your desired output.
    }
}
```

Comment: This method would work, I'm sure, but it's not as elegant or as quick as I'd like. The database stores around 1mil records with a few thousand unique sequence numbers, so I fear this may have a severe performance impact when asking for a few unique rows constantly.

Comment: Let me know if you find a better way... I am interested to know.

Comment: I suppose if you could add a `WHERE` to the initial query and only query results after a given time that you are positive the sequence started after. It would greatly reduce the records returned.  Maybe even given a time period. The more info you provide, the more efficient it will be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after here. I wrote some code that will work if the data is in a text file. If the data is in a database, it would be easier. However, I assumed since in your example you have a | separating the data that it's not in a database.

```
function findLastOccurenceOfSequence ($sequenceNumber)
{
    if (@!is_int ($sequenceNumber))
        throw new Exception ("Expected param1 to be an integer");
    $data = file_get_contents ("testFile.txt");
    $dataArray = explode ("\n", $data);
    $dataArray = array_reverse ($dataArray);
    $returnLine = "";
    $sequenceStarted = false;
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => &$dataLine)
    {
        $pieces = explode ("|", $dataLine);
        if (count ($pieces) != 2)
            continue;
        list ($thisSequenceNum, $timeStamp) = $pieces;
        $thisSequenceNum = intval (trim ($thisSequenceNum));
        if ($thisSequenceNum == $sequenceNumber)
        {
            $sequenceStarted = true;
            $returnLine = $dataLine;
        }
        else if ($sequenceStarted)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($key == count ($dataArray))
    {
        throw new Exception ("Sequence not found!");
    }

    return $returnLine;
}

echo "OCCURRENCE: " . findLastOccurenceOfSequence (2);
```